# How to parameterize path of url in visual studio web performance test project?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, performance-testing

I am using the visual studio 2010 to test my web system.

I recorded many request.

http:// 10.20.30.40/system_name/aa.aspx

http:// 10.20.30.40/system_name/bb.aspx

http:// 10.20.30.40/system_name/cc.aspx

I used the Parameterize Web Servers function. This function only allows me to change the ip.

then the request url is changed to...

{{WebServer1}}/system_name/aa.aspx

{{WebServer1}}/system_name/bb.aspx

{{WebServer1}}/system_name/cc.aspx

so I created a context parameters, p1=sys_name

but I need to change every request manually.

{{WebServer1}}/{{p1}}/aa.aspx

It will spend too much time.

May I know how to do that automatically in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

Use this fantastic feature : Find and Replace in Request.

[image]

Right Click on one of your requests, Specify your parameters, and click on Replace All.